# logistic regression r user output

Tags: sql, r, statistics

On a daily basis i run a sql query that give me new data for my regression model. I import the data into R run the model then export the data with the probabilities to excel. I use this excel file to send to different users. It stratifies the probabilities into High-Med-Low risk and makes the overall document easier to read ie formatting and colors.

My question is: What options do i have to automate this process? How else can i make this information available to the end user on a daily basis?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at the shiny package, you can set a timer with invalidateLater to refresh your data and do the calculations again.

Comment: You could also set up a cron job to run your script at the desired intervals, maybe saving a resulting csv to a shared Dropbox folder. You could even have R send out a tweet to let your users know that there's a new file available.

Comment: Agree with cron job. Rmarkdown via knitr/pandoc to an HTML page (possibly password-protected)?  You can presumably run the SQL query from within R.